# What do these git commands mean, in case of making my branch identical to some remote branch?

Tags: git

The project I was working on had many branches of which there were two branches of my concern `sprint1` and `sprint2`. I created a new branch for my work `lexis` from branch `sprint1` and made `1` commit to the branch `lexis`. Later my team mate told that I should have branched from `sprint2` instead of `sprint1`. So he did the following

```
On branch lexis he deleted my commit
git fetch origin/sprint2
git reset --hard origin/sprint2
Then he cherry picked my commit from reflog
```

Then he told me to push my commit on branch `lexis` using `push -f`.
My doubts are

1. I know the reseting makes my branch `lexis` exactly like `sprint 2`. But why did he do a `git fetch` ?
2. Why was `git psh -f` used ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But why did he do a git fetch ?

To make sure to use the most recent updated `sprint2` branch

> Why was `git push -f` used ?

If you already did push `lexis`, you need to force push it considering its history would have changed (since its base is no longer `sprint1` but `sprint2`)

Answer (score 3):

I think that seeing a diagram of what is happening here would be most beneficial to you.

Initially, let's assume that both `lexis` and `sprint2` started off the same:

```
sprint2: ... A -- B -- C
lexis:   ... A -- B -- C
```

Here, I used ellipsis to represent everything which came before this.  Presumably, they were both branched off a common base at some point, but this isn't really relevant to your question.  You made one commit to `lexis`, and at the same time, other people made some number (let's say 2) of commits to `sprint2`.  At this point, the diagram looks like this:

```
sprint2: ... A -- B -- C -- D -- E
lexis:   ... A -- B -- C -- F
```

At this point, you should have been on top of `sprint2`, but you committed to `sprint1` instead.  Your colleague then nuked your commit `F`, leaving us with:

```
sprint2: ... A -- B -- C -- D -- E
lexis:   ... A -- B -- C
```

Then, he did the following two commands from branch `lexis`:

```
git fetch origin/sprint2         # update local tracking branch for sprint2
git reset --hard origin/sprint2  # reset local lexis to sprint2
```

This left the diagrams looking like this:

```
sprint2: ... A -- B -- C -- D -- E
lexis:   ... A -- B -- C -- D -- E
```

Finally, he cherry-picked your commit `F` onto this new base:

```
sprint2: ... A -- B -- C -- D -- E
lexis:   ... A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F'
```

Now, you are where you want to be.  You have one single commit on top of the current base `sprint2`.

Note that the final step looked something like this:

```
git push --force origin lexis
```

This is necessary because the base of your branch changed and needs to overwritten forcibly.

Answer (score 1):

The `git fetch` was just to make sure you had an up-to-date snapshot of `sprint2`.

`git push -f` was necessary because your local copy of `lexis`, after the `git reset`, had diverged from the remote copy. (Think of it as the `push` version of `git reset --hard`; regardless of what `origin/lexis` looks like, make it look like the local `lexis` now.)